# How do I set up Ventrilo Push-to-Talk to work with an XBox 360 controller?

Tags: controllers, ventrilo

I have been playing some Champions Online on the PC, and for that I like to use my XBox 360 controller. However, I also like to use Push-to-Talk in Ventrilo to talk with my friends.

I couldn't find a way to get Ventrilo working with a button on the controller (say, Lb). Is there a way to set that up?

I tried JoyToKey but couldn't figure out how to get that working either.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Xpadder](http://www.xpadder.com/).

Comment: +1 for Xpadder. You are going to have to use something that will map one of your gamepad keys to a keyboard key. There are other solutions out there if you do a touch of Googling.